# Like Operator equivalent in LINQ

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq, sql-like

I need to use the like operator in a LINQ query

For this:

```
timb = time.Timbratures.Include("Anagrafica_Dipendente")
                .Where(p => p.Anagrafica_Dipendente.Cognome + " " + p.Anagrafica_Dipendente.Nome like "%ci%");
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
timb = time.Timbratures.Include("Anagrafica_Dipendente")
           .Where(p => (p.Anagrafica_Dipendente.Cognome + " "
                       + p.Anagrafica_Dipendente.Nome).Contains("ci"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Contains() for this like so:

```
var query = (from p in products
            where p.Description.Contains("ci")
            select p);
```